# Plotting the one second mean of bytes from a time series in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: performance, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, average

I have 15 minutes of data in a DataFrame I named `netflow_df`. I want to plot bytes per second, but with a one second mean. - And have a straight line for each second in the plot.

```
print netflow_df[["timestamp", "bytes"]].tail(50)

                 timestamp  bytes
947636 2016-09-29 09:25:39   3782
947637 2016-09-29 09:25:25   3180
947638 2016-09-29 09:25:25   3180
947639 2016-09-29 09:25:46  10068
947640 2016-09-29 09:25:41   3072
947641 2016-09-29 09:25:46   3480
947642 2016-09-29 09:25:46   2382
947643 2016-09-29 09:25:46   3678
947644 2016-09-29 09:25:46   2382
947645 2016-09-29 09:25:46   2966
947646 2016-09-29 09:25:47     80
947647 2016-09-29 09:25:46   4060
947648 2016-09-29 09:25:40   3712
947649 2016-09-29 09:25:46   4016
```

I prepare the data-set:

```
netflow_df["timestamp"] = pandas.to_datetime(netflow_df['timestamp'])
netflow_df["bytes"] = netflow_df["bytes"].astype(int)
netflow_df = netflow_df.sort_values(by='timestamp')
netflow_df.timestamp.values
```

I select an interval within this data-set. This marks an activity time-frame.

```
# We plot the active timeframe
import matplotlib

%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0)

# reindex by time
netflow_df.set_index(['timestamp'])
netflow_df2 = netflow_df[(netflow_df['timestamp'] > act_time_s) & (netflow_df['timestamp'] <= act_time_e)]
```

Now for the plot... this is kind of useless for now.

[image]

This is useless because the y axis does not represent the byte throughput I am looking for. Practically 1 kilobyte is 1024 bytes. I haven't found a way to make Pandas / Matplotlib aware of the unit, so that it can convert them. This way I cannot read the plot without a calculator ;)

I also don't understand this warning for my context:

> /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:2:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

Now, in order to get the 1s mean (straight lines for each 1s interval) I have attempted to group by 1s. `df2` is the selected timeframe here. `df3` is the grouped DataFrame.

```
# group in 1s intervals
netflow_df3 = netflow_df2.groupby(netflow_df2["timestamp"].map(lambda t: t.second))
for index, one_sec_group in netflow_df3:
    avg = one_sec_group["bytes"].mean()
    print avg
    for record in one_sec_group:
        one_sec_group["avg_bytes"] = avg
```

This prints the avg, but it takes a lot (horrible!) of computation time and I don't know how to access the `avg_bytes` for the plot. One of my earlier tests was interpolating the plot, but this looks miserable as well. For reference:

```
netflow_df2["bytes"] = netflow_df2["bytes"].interpolate(method='cubic', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.resample` method:

```
>>> netflow_df2 = netflow_df2.set_index('timestamp')
>>> netflow_df2.resample('1s').mean().plot()
```

As for your unit problem, you can simply divide the bytes column by 1024 (for instance).

```
>>> netflow_df2['kilobytes'] = netflow_df2['bytes']/1024
```

Comment: I just tested that since I am not really familiar with these functions. It requires a DateTimeIndex or a PeriodIndex.